# Cypher - How is negation handled?

Tags: database, graph, cypher, negation

I have been trying to understand how Cypher corresponds to graph database theory. In particular I had in mind "Query Languages for Graph Databases by Peter T.Wood" (http://users.dcc.uchile.cl/~pbarcelo/wood.pdf). I imagine that it corresponds to conjunctive regular path queries with additional operations such as aggregation but I cannot find information about this anywhere.

Two question:

1. Is there anywhere I can find information about the theory behind Cypher? In particular with a conjunctive query spin.
2. How does Cypher handle negation? e.g. is it 'safe negation'?

Background: I started using Neo4j with Cypher for a paper that I'm working on. I did this because these both seemed well established and well supported. However, I want to abstract away from my implementation of query answering to a more general graph query formalism but I do not know how Cypher corresponds to this.

Comment: I asked the same comment on Linkedin and got a very comprehensive and authoritative answer here https://www.linkedin.com/groups/Does-anybody-know-similarities-differences-2623939.S.5939804856381382658.

Comment: Hey Michael, You can copy the answers you received there and paste as an answer here. This way, people with the same doubts can get a faster answer and we do not have rely on linkedin being online. Of course, you can add the same link you provided as a source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer to this question on LinkedIn which can be found here:
https://www.linkedin.com/groups/Does-anybody-know-similarities-differences-2623939.S.5939804856381382658

The answer below refers to this query:

> MATCH (n:Asteroid) WHERE NOT n.name = 'Ceres' RETURN n LIMIT 25

The answer is as follows:

> There are two answers to your question regarding negation:
>
> (i) The negation of a property value
>
> This is the case covered in the comment above, which is essentially
>   correct; I will re-use the provided example. Internally, all nodes
>   having the label 'Asteroid' are retrieved using the label index. This
>   is followed by a “selection” operator (from relational algebra), which
>   is used to select only those tuples containing either no 'name'
>   property or where the 'name' property is not 'Ceres'.This is then
>   followed by an operator called “top”, limiting the results returned to
>   25. As you can see, this does not differ from how SQL is executed on relational databases.
>
> (ii) The negation of a pattern predicate
>
> This is where the full power of graph pattern matching is utilised.
>
> Say we have the following toy query, in which I want to find all
>   events I have not attended:
>
> MATCH (me:Person {name: “me”}), (e:Event)  WHERE NOT ( (me) -
>   [:ATTENDED] -> (e) )  RETURN e
>
> Our query execution plan is a tree of operators, each of which has up
>   to 2 children.
>
> At root of the tree, we have an 'Anti Semi Apply' operator (equivalent
>   to an anti-semijoin operator in relational theory). The left-hand
>   child is a Cartesian Product of two sets of tuples: (1) a set of nodes
>   corresponding to (me:Person {name: "me"}) retrieved using the label
>   and property index, and (2) a set of nodes corresponding to (e:Event),
>   retrieved using the label index. We note that the Cartesian Product
>   will consist of all combinations of "me" nodes with *every* (e:Event)
>   in the database.
>
> The Cartesian Product emits a single row at a time, and this row, R,
>   is piped upwards to the Anti Semi Apply operator. The Anti Semi Apply
>   then feeds R as an argument to its right-hand branch, so that R
>   appears as the ultimate descendant on the right-hand side. R is passed
>   upwards to an Expand operator, which returns all
>   (me)-[:ATTENDED]-(some_e) rows (note that the "me" here matches the
>   one in R). Immediately, each such row, S, has a Selection operation
>   applied to it, in order to match "some_e" to the "e" in R. Thus, any
>   row S is in effect an "Event" ATTEND by "me". S is then piped to Anti
>   Semi Apply. If *no* row S was found for R, R is returned as a result
>   (as these will be all “Events” *not* ATTENDED by "me")
>
> Thus, having negation in a query is not treated as a simple filter -
>   it intrinsically affects the entire query plan.
>
> More details on Cypher’s execution plans can be found at
>   http://neo4j.com/docs/snapshot/execution-plans.html.